# Capture weight of a Mettler Toledo truck Scale using serialport

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I got a code online to read via rs232 using serial port ,the code uses readExisting() to get the data(im geting data form a MettlerToledo scale connected at com3,9600,8,N,1)problem now is that i change it to ReadLine() but it captures the weight once and i need the weight updated all the time! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop of some form

```
While someBoolean
   'Read the serial port
End While
```

I would suggest putting this on a BackGroundWorker as to not interrupt the main thread

Or you could use a Timer

```
Dim weightTimer As Timer = new Timer(100) 'pick either the threading or the Forms timer depending

    'Using the Forms timer for the example
    'Handle the timer tick event
    Private Sub weightTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles weightTimer.Tick
       'Read the Serial Port
    End Sub
```